# php_zip.dll is missing from PHP 5.5 for Windows

Tags: php, windows

I downloaded PHP 5.5. for Windows and trying to install Composer.

Later I found that Composer need Zip extension. But `php_zip.dll` file is missing from PHP 5.5 zip I downloaded from php.net website.

Where can I find this missing `php_zip.dll`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess previous versions of PHP shipped with `php_zip.dll`. Why they dropped this file from their zip?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846553/php-zip-does-not-exist-in-php-5-3-5 - php_zip is included in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php You may have to install the Zip extension manually. Apparently the Windows procedure is different, so you should probably just read for yourself. Or just reinstall PHP/WAMP and see if there was something wrong with your installation to begin with. Edit: Oh wait! Lookie. Did you make sure it's checked here? (Assuming you're using WAMP) http://i.imgur.com/pUknn8p.png

Comment: @Ariane, found that PHP 5.5 includes zip in it's core and it is enabled by default. Thanks.

Comment: I saw. Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the Answer.

1. Remove `;extension=php_zip.dll` line in `php.ini`.
2. Restart Apache HTTP Server.

Previous versions of PHP shipped with separate `php_zip.dll` file in `ext` folder. And we need to enable (comment out the `;extension=php_zip.dll` line in `php.ini`) the zip extension manually.

Latest version - `PHP 5.5` includes this `zip` support in core and it is enabled by default.

But the line `;extension=php_zip.dll` was left there in `php.ini` even though it is not needed.

As usual after installing `PHP 5.5`, I enabled (commented out) `;extension=php_zip.dll` line in `php.ini`, thinking that it is a separate extension.

In this case, Composer couldn't find `php_zip.dll`.

I removed the `;extension=php_zip.dll` line in `php.ini`.

Restarted Apache HTTP Server.

Worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

The PHP 5.5 build for Windows that I installed from windows.php.net did not come with /ext/php_zip.dll, so I had to download the latest dll file for my Windows 8 x64 Non-Thread-Safe system and copy it into my php ext directory: http://pecl.php.net/package/zip/1.12.4/windows